# Cherrypy with Mysql error: "tuple indices must be integers, not str" when trying to add users

Tags: python, mysql, cherrypy

guys, I'm having this random error on my Project when trying to register users.

This is the information that is returned from the browser.

```
{Gender: "M", ReEmail: "heyguys@whatup.com", Birthday: "1/19/1980", Role: "Athlete",…}
Birthday: "1/19/1980"
Country: "United States"
Email: "heyguys@whatup.com"
Gender: "M"
Password:"doesntwork123"
ReEmail:"heyguys@whatup.com"
RePassword:"doesntwork123"
Role:"Athlete"
kwargs:{}
method:"POST"
results:{error: "tuple indices must be integers, not str"}
error: "tuple indices must be integers, not str"
```

By using PyCharm debugger, I have centralized the problem to this specific part

```
def addUser(self, session, *args, **kwargs):
   try:
    #existingPerson = session.query(person_models.Player).filter(person_models.Player.Email==args['Email']).first()
    print person_models.Player
    print person_models.Player.Email
    existingPerson = session.query(person_models.Player).filter(person_models.Player.Email == args['Email']).first()
    print existingPerson
    if existingPerson is not None:
       return {'error':"User already exists"}
    person_model = getattr(person_models)
    person = person_model(*args)
    session.add(person)
    session.commit()
    return {"response": "User added"}
   except Exception as e:
    return {'error':str(e)}
```

Once it gets to existing person, it sends me directly to the exception. This is when it gives me  "tuple indices must be integers, not str"

---

Here is some additional code.

Here is some code:

webapi.py

```
import cherrypy
from api.restBase import jsonDbRest
from person.controllers import PersonController
class PersonAPI:
exposed = True

@jsonDbRest
def GET(self, email=False, **kwargs):
  session = cherrypy.request.db
  pc = PersonController()
  if email in kwargs:
        profile = pc.get(session, **kwargs)
        return {"results":[profile], "count":'1'}
  profile = pc.search(session, **kwargs)
  return {"results":profile.to_dict(), "count":'1'}

@jsonDbRest
def POST(self, *args, **kwargs):
   session = cherrypy.request.db
   pc = PersonController()
   response = pc.addUser(session, *args, **kwargs)
   return {"results": response}
```

It's complaining about line 15.

Here is another line that is using the code:

restbase.py

```
import cherrypy
import json
from engine import create_session

def jsonDbRest(func):
  def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):

  cherrypy.request.db = create_session()

  if 'Content-Length' in cherrypy.request.headers:
     length = cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length']
     bodytext = cherrypy.request.body.fp.read(int(length))
  else:
     bodytext = ""
  if bodytext != "":
     jsonData = json.loads(bodytext)
  else:
     jsonData = None
  cherrypy.request.json = jsonData
  func_data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  data = {"method":func.__name__, "input":jsonData,"kwargs":kwargs}
  if func_data is not None:
     data.update(func_data)
  cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  if "error" in data:
     cherrypy.response.status = "400"
  else:
     cherrypy.response.status = "200"
  cherrypy.request.db.close()
  return json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

return wrapper

Another code

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import AbstractConcreteBase
import datetime
import decimal
import netaddr
import sqlalchemy
from time import strftime

class Base(object):
  def to_dict(self):
    dict = {}
    dict = self.__dict__
    remove = '_sa_instance_state'
    dict = {key: value for key, value in dict.items() if key is not remove}
    dict['DateOfBirth'] = dict['DateOfBirth'].strftime('%m/%d/%Yi')

    return dict

def from_dict(self, dict):
  for col in dict:
     setattr(self, col, dict[col])

def to_array(self, columns=[]):
  if len(columns) < 1:
     columns = self.__mapper__.columns.keys()
  data = []
  for col in columns:
     data.append(getattr(self, col))
  return data

def get_columns(self):
  return self.__mapper__.columns.keys()

JsonBase = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is on the first sample:

```
existingPerson = session.query(person_models.Player).filter(person_models.Player.Email == args['Email']).first()
```

Try with `kwargs` instead of `args`:

```
existingPerson = session.query(person_models.Player).filter(person_models.Player.Email == kwargs['Email']).first()
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your reply and I have done that before and implemented it just as you recommended. What happens is that it goes directly to except and prints out an error. I have been trying to trace the error for a while now but can't seem to figure out what the cause is!

What is printed with kwargs is

    'Email'

Comment: Are you aware of the builtin json tool in cherrypy?  You seems to be setting the attribute `cherrypy.request.json` similar to the builtin tool. http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html?#dealing-with-json